# Install Android app in Eclipse without running it

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-install-apk

I'm using Eclipse to develop a bunch of Android apps and I need to batch install them, either on the emulator or on an attached device. I'd like to be able to push them all to the device without running them individually in Eclipse.

How can I do that?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use a script (in command line) to do this?  I would write a script to use adb and "batch" install these.

Comment: I just wanted a way to do it from within Eclipse for convenience, like using ant. Guess I'll go make a bat file. Now if only I could figure out parallel installs.

Comment: if that is the case, check out using Eclipse's external tools configuration: http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/concepts-exttools.htm This will allow you to specify a batch file, shell script, etc, and roll it into a Eclipse Build process, and have it "do it all" at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using adb.

```
adb install -r your/path/to/file.apk
```

-r is forced install.

You can also create a batch file with number of `adb install` commands.

Answer (score 0):

You could just push them to the emulator using "adb install fileN.apk" from the command line.